# How to upload file in phantomjs headless browser using selenium+java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

```
**How to upload file in phantomjs headless browser using selenium+java?**
```

I have already tried :
(PhantomJSDriver) driver.executePhantomJS("var page = this; page.uploadFile('input[type=file]', 'path to file');");

Comment: @DebanjanB any idea how to solve this?

Comment: it worked with same above code.Actually there was some issue with my own code :)